# Conditional Formatting for yearly leave roster

Tags: excel

I have been trying for days to get the conditional formatting correct to highlight days in my calendar when someone are on leave.

I'm using this formula which I got from other website:

```
=IF((INDEX(StartDate,SMALL(IF($A17=FullName,MATCH(ROW(StartDate),ROW(StartDate)),""),COUNTIF($A$17:$A17,$A17)))<=C$15)*((INDEX(EndDate,SMALL(IF($A17=FullName,MATCH(ROW(StartDate),ROW(StartDate)),""),COUNTIF($A$17:$A17,$A17)))>=C$15)),SUMPRODUCT((StartDate<=C$15)*(EndDate>=C$15))>1,FALSE)
```

Example of main screen:

[image: spreadsheet showing multiple rows and columns]

This formula works but the problem is only pick up one person and one date. For example in my table source it's listed `fullname`, `StartDate` and `Enddate` which under fullname there would be 3 or 4 SAME fullname but with different startdate and enddate. the formula above only pick up the small one as it's using SMALL function.

Can anyone give my any kind of lights of how I can do this?

Comment: Do you want to highlight the username cell when someone is on a leave, or do you want to highlight the whole username row when someone is on leave?

Comment: I want to highlight the date in the row for that name. For ex: based on my source table 'aa' will have annual leave from 06/07/2016 until 08/07/2016, then cells H17, I17, J18 will be highlighted (based on my example of my main screen).

Comment: Where are you storing your Start and End Date information? On a separate sheet?

Comment: I stored Fullname, start and end date on the other sheets (tab).